# How to download the HR schema on Oracle XE 21c?

Tags: oracle21c

My instructor wants me for a h.w to download oracle database and show him the HR schema. However, I noticed that the HR schema is not available within the downloaded files of oracle xe 21c. So is there a way to download the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (very) [quick search on Oracle's documentation website](https://docs.oracle.com/search/?q=sample+schema) leads you to:

- [The installation guide for Oracle's sample schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-1E645D09-F91F-4BA6-A286-57C5EC66321D); and
- [Oracle's Github repository for the sample schemas](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/releases/latest).